# Add event to item in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, events, mvvm

In my xaml file with DataTemplates I want to add a DataContextChanged event to my ListBox that is in one of the templates, so i do this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <ListBox Background="Transparent"
             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             DataContextChanged="MyListBox_DataContextChanged"
             SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelSegment, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But in which file to implement "MyListBox_DataContextChanged"?

Comment: Well it looks like you already created an eventhandler in the codebehind of your view. But as you added the tag MVVM you should probably consider adding a command to your viewmodel and binding that command to the DataContextChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

when working with Mvvm you don't handle events directly like you do when working with code behind, in your case the command that handles the `DataContextChanged` should be implemented in the corresponding ViewModel of the page where this `DataTemplate` is used, 
and finally using a simple hack you can execute the associated Command when the `DataContextChanged` Event accured, your code should looks like so :
The Xaml :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <ListBox Background="Transparent"
             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}"          
             SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelSegment, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DataContextChanged">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=MyViewModel.MyListBox_DataContextChangedCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and Add the following command to your ViewModel :

```
 private RelayCommand __myListBox_DataContextChangedCommand;
        public RelayCommand MyListBox_DataContextChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return __myListBox_DataContextChangedCommand
                    ?? (__myListBox_DataContextChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    () =>
                    {
                        //Your Event's Handler Goes Here
                    }));
            }
        }
```

**Edit** :

You could read more about `EventToCommand` at 
[Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Comment: i:Interaction.Triggers and command:EventToCommand are not found (its a Windows Phone 8.1 app). Do i need to add something in the XAML?

Comment: @V.G. you didn't tag the Windows Phone 8.1 in your question !,any way that should work fine on any silverlight based app, but it seems that there are a lack of support in the last WinPRT version, i didn't get the chance to work with it yet, here an article about the subject, hope it will help you http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/  ...regards